Slope compensation in peak current mode control
There is a statement in the slope compensation section, page 25, of the UCC28950 phase shift full bridge document as follows, and shown in the picture below:
“Part of this ramp will be due to magnetizing current in the transformer, the rest is added by an appropriately chosen resistor from RSUM to ground.”
I know what slope compensation is for, but I don't fully understand how the magnetizing current in the circuit forms a part of the slope compensation?
How does it contribute to the slope compensation?

Source: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf

What is the magnetizing current waveform? What is the slope compensation waveform? What if any similarities do they have?

In a forward transformer, the primary-side current is made of two components, the magnetizing current \$i_{mag}(t)\$ and the secondary-side current \$i_L(t)\$, reflected via the transformer turns ratio. The magnetizing current is created when the power switch turns on and applies the input voltage across the transformer primary. This is what is represented in the below image excerpted from a PPT I published years ago about the over-power issue in a forward converter.

During this mode, the magnetizing current starts from zero - this current in a forward is discontinuous - and increases until the switch turns off. However, the series diode in the sec side is also forward-biased during this time and the inductor current circulates in the secondary winding.
In the MOSFET drain and then in the source, the total current is thus the reflected secondary current plus that ramp coming from the magnetizing inductance. As such, it works as a free stabilizing ramp which is going to reduce the current-loop gain. In a classical current-mode power supply, you sum the voltage collected across the current-sense resistance with an extra artificial voltage ramp to compensate the converter. Here, the voltage collected across the sense resistance is already supplemented with the magnetizing current which acts like the artificial current ramp you are familiar with, except that you do not need to externally produce it as it is already there in the forward.
Sometimes there is too much ramp and there is not much you can do; the converter is overcompensated. But in some other cases, the magnetizing ramp is not enough and you have to supplement it with some artificial ramp. This doc shows in the first slide how it works. It is also covered in details in my 2021 book on transfer functions.
